# How to create new custom event page in the admin area

Tags: wordpress, civievent, admin

I have set the "Custom PHP Directory" as [civicrm.files]/custom_php/
Under custom_php/ I have created the folders CRM -> Event -> Page -> SessionTypes.php
I have added the menu as a hook under Events (in the admin area) which points to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/sessiontypes but the page does not get hit.
What am I missing? Below is the content of the SessionTypes.php

require_once 'CRM/Core/Page.php';
class CRM_Event_Page_SessionTypes extends CRM_Core_Page {
  function run() {
    die('innn');
    parent::run();
  }
}

Comment: The menu hook page does not explain as to how to make that page working: civicrm/trends
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_navigationMenu

Comment: First try make the changes directly in the core and test it

Comment: Where in core? .

Comment: I think i've tracked it down - it needs a record in table civicrm_menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alongside with civicrm_navigationMenu (which only creates the menu item) I had to use the hook civicrm_xmlMenu which is where you specify the xml file that manages the record for civicrm_menu. This is where civicrm knows what the page_callback is for every path i.e. civicrm/sessiontypes